# How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in python

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to django and wanted some guidance on my project. I want to create a web application for managing traffic violations. Where do I have to start?

Here is an example of analysis generated with windev:

[image: Relationship diagram generated by windev]

Comment: Please can you provide some code or a specific issue that you are stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

What you have pictured is represented in Django by `classes` called `models`.

Nevertheless, you should start by learning Django from the [official documentation](https://www.djangoproject.com/). Additionally, check out the video courses which may be more affordable.